# PHP - accesing to data of multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to access data in a multi-dimenstional array. 
I need to get values of this data `(EC000001, EG000017, EN, EF007220)` but I am struggling with foreach loops in PHP, especially when need to nested foreach Could you please help me and give me solution to access wanted data?

I need to loop over all $c's and then loop inside to get all needed data.This is how I collected value EC000001 before, but I believe that there is a better solution.

```
   foreach ($c as $classCodes => $value) {

    $classCode = key($c[$classCodes]); //classCode -> EC000001
}
```

Structure of array:

```
Array
(
    **[EC000001]** => Array
        (
            [0] => **EG000017**
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => **EN**
                            [1] => Busbar terminal
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => **nl-NL**
                            [1] => Aansluitklem stroomrail
                        )
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => **EF007220**
                            [1] => EU570448
                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => EF007219
                            [1] => EU570448
                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => EF000073
                            [1] => 
                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => EV009241
                                    [1] => EV009472
                                )
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => EF007092
                            [1] => EU570448
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => EF004969
                            [1] => EU570126     
                        )
                )
        )

)
```

Comment: Paste the text of the structure of the array, not an image.

Comment: @cale_b I did this. Hope that problem is better explained now.

Comment: @punky see my answer

Comment: Now you need to identify clearly what the result should be.  Your example `(EC000001, EG000017, EN, EF007220)` is incomplete, and feels arbitrary.  What is this structure?

Answer (score 0):

I can not test it, but you can try with this inside the loop:

```
$value[0];       // -> 1
$value[1][0][0]; // -> 2
$value[1][1][1]; // -> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$EG000002Array[0][EG000001][0]

$EG000002Array[0][EG000001][1][0]

$EG000002Array[0][EG000001][1][1][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to get array values from multi dimensional array

for example using  foreach():

```
    $flavors = array('Japanese' => array('hot' => 'wasabi',
                                     'salty' => 'soy sauce'),
                 'Chinese'  => array('hot' => 'mustard',
                                     'pepper-salty' => 'prickly ash'));

// $culture is the key and $culture_flavors is the value (an array)
foreach ($flavors as $culture => $culture_flavors) {

    // $flavor is the key and $example is the value
    foreach ($culture_flavors as $flavor => $example) {
        print "A $culture $flavor flavor is $example.\n";
    }
}
```

or using for( ) :

```
$specials = array( array('Chestnut Bun', 'Walnut Bun', 'Peanut Bun'),
                   array('Chestnut Salad','Walnut Salad', 'Peanut Salad') );

// $num_specials is 2: the number of elements in the first dimension of $specials
for ($i = 0, $num_specials = count($specials); $i < $num_specials; $i++) {
    // $num_sub is 3: the number of elements in each sub-array
    for ($m = 0, $num_sub = count($specials[$i]); $m < $num_sub; $m++) {
        print "Element [$i][$m] is " . $specials[$i][$m] . "\n";
    }
}
```

the output should be like :

```
Element [0][0] is Chestnut Bun
Element [0][1] is Walnut Bun
Element [0][2] is Peanut Bun
Element [1][0] is Chestnut Salad
Element [1][1] is Walnut Salad
Element [1][2] is Peanut Salad
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **recursion** and **regex** to check if it's bolded :)

> Notice we put`&` to `$classCodes` to pass it by **reference** and not
>   by **value**.

**Function:**

```
function get_bolded_data($c, &$classCodes = array()){
    foreach($c as $k1 => $v1){
        if(is_array($v1)){
            //If $v1 is an array we call get_bolded_data() again and pass 
            //$v1 and $classCode
            get_bolded_data($v1,$classCodes);
        }else if(preg_match("/(\*\*).*(\*\*)/", $v1)){
            $classCodes[] = $v1;
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$classCodes = array();
$c = array(
    0 => array(
        '**EC000001**' => array(
            0 => '**EG000017**',
            1 => array(
                0 => array(
                    0 => '**EN**',
                    1 => 'Busbar terminal'
                ) ,
                1 => array(
                    0 => '**nl-NL**',
                    1 => 'Aansluitklem stroomrail'
                )
            ) ,
            2 => array(
                0 => array(
                    0 => '**EF007220**',
                    1 => 'EU570448',
                    2 => array()
                ) ,
                1 => array(
                    0 => 'EF007219',
                    1 => 'EU570448',
                    2 => array()
                ) ,
                2 => array(
                    0 => 'EF000073',
                    1 => '',
                    2 => array(
                        0 => 'EV009241',
                        1 => 'EV009472'
                    )
                ) ,
                3 => array(
                    0 => 'EF007092',
                    1 => 'EU570448'
                ) ,
                4 => array(
                    0 => 'EF004969',
                    1 => 'EU570126'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
//Call our function
get_bolded_data($c, $classCodes);
```

**Here is the result from var_dump:**

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "**EG000017**"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "**EN**"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "**nl-NL**"
  [3]=>
  string(12) "**EF007220**"
}
```